# How to deal with "I don't know where to start" questions

Tags: discussion, community

I think we are all familiar with the Stack Exchange Data Science question like the following:

"I have this really cool idea for this project that I would like to work on where I take stock data and predict future returns! I have some experience with Machine Learning - the only problem I have is that I don't know where to start with the code. Any suggestions?"

I think, we have all probably seen some variation of this question. I found myself commenting the other day on a post like this with "For clarification - have you worked with Tensorflow before or are you familiar with LSTM architecture?" To which the response was silent.

My question is, how should we as community members address these types of questions going forward? It seems like there is a small amount of people who take to the site to ask for help with their ideas but have no prior experience with coding or ML.

Comment: This kind of questions is usually "unclear" (what *specific* issue do you face?) or "too broad" (you need tutorials on many different topics to get started).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Agree, these just aren't a good fit for SE sites and should be closed as too broad or unclear. If someone is truly that new to even how to frame a question about data science, I don't think an SE site is the place to learn. If they do know and are just looking for ideas, it's not a good fit for the format. If they're just wanting someone to do the legwork to collect basic info and could do it themselves - we need to discourage it.